# how to display an image with the grid.lua lib

Tags: arrays, image, lua, grid

i have found this lib for easily create a grid in lua but i can't assign an image on each cells.
https://github.com/CoderDojoSV/corona-game-template/blob/master/docs/grid.md

I have contacted the author of the grid.lua but no answer anymore.
Do you have the true syntax ? thanks for your help.

```
local grid = require("grid")

myGrid = grid.newGrid(5, 5, 500) 
myGrid:eachSquare(function(doeach)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in documentation grid is based on rectangle objects, so you won't be able to assging image to grid directly.
But you can put image in each squares coordinates

Base on docs:

```
local myGrid = grid.newGrid(8, 8, 700)
myGrid:eachSquare(function(gridSquare)
     local image = display.newImage(pathToYourImage)
     image.x, image.y = gridSquare.displayObject.x, gridSquare.displayObject.y
end)
```

If you need reference in grid squares to image you can assign it to gridSquare

```
gridSquare.myImage = image
```

That way in every further eachSquare iteration you will have access to image reference.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response. But the return is : attempt to call method 'eachSquare' (a nil value)


    local grid = require("grid")
    grid.newGrid(8, 8, 720)
    grid:eachSquare(function(gridSquare)
    local image = display.newImage(my2.png)
    image.x, image.y = gridSquare.displayObject.x, gridSquare.displayObject.y
    end)

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution

```
grille:eachSquare(function(gridSquare)
gridSquare.displayObject:setFillColor(0, 0, 0, 255)
gridSquare.displayObject.xScale=.1
gridSquare.displayObject.yScale=1
gridSquare.myImage = display.newImage("my2.png") 
gridSquare.myImage.x = gridSquare.displayObject.x+35
gridSquare.myImage.y = gridSquare.displayObject.y
gridSquare.myImage.yScale=0.5
gridSquare.myImage.xScale=0.5
end)
```

Comment: Basicly it's same as my solution.